# Age pyramid chart using chart.js

Tags: chart.js

I'm trying to create a chart using chart.js like this one (for example):

https://thebreadoflifeblog.files.wordpress.com/2013/01/uk-age-pyramid.png

I tried multiple possibilities and so far, the best one I found is using a simple trick of merging two horizontalBar charts:

[image]

But there are actually some problems.

1. As I said, this is actually two different charts. I would like to have only one object.
2. I removed the yAxis. I could leave one to display the yAxis labels, but in that case, one of the two graphics will be smaller than the other one. I would like the labels to be displayed between both charts.
3. The chart on the left is using negative value to achieve the right to left bars. Is there a way to 'revert' an axis ? I saw there is a 'Scale' method, but it seems complicated for just reverting the axis...

I would like to know if there is something I can do to create such chart easier and, most important, as one unique chart.

Answer (score 2):

I ran up against the same problems as you, and managed to fix it using React ChartJS' HorizontalBarChart: but only one ;-)

Try stacking the yAxis and adding two datasets, using the options property

```
const populationPyramidOptions = {
scales: {
    yAxes: [{
        stacked: true
    }],
    xAxes: [{
        stacked: false
    }]
}


<HorizontalBar data={chartData} options={populationPyramidOptions} />
```

You can get a pretty good result:

[image: Population Pyramid using ChartJS]

Answer (score 1):

if you use directly chartjs check about the solution here:
https://github.com/nknganda/pyramid_chart_example

The syntax for the options is not compatible with chartjs > 3.x

Below the updated code:

```
options = {
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      intersect: true,
      callbacks: {
        label: function(context) {
          var label = context.dataset.label || '';
          var value = context.formattedValue;
          var positiveOnly = value < 0 ? -value : value;
          if (label) {
              label += ': ';
          }
          if (context.parsed.y !== null) {
              label += positiveOnly
          }
          return label;
        },
      },
     },
    legend: {
      position: "bottom",
    },
  },
  responsive: true,
  scales: {
     x: {
      stacked: false,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
        callback: (v) => {
          return v < 0 ? -v : v;
        },
      },
     },
    y: {
       stacked: true,
      ticks: {
        beginAtZero: true,
      },
      position: "left",
    },
   },
   indexAxis: 'y'
 }
```

Note that tooltips is now tooltip and inside plugins, alongside with legend.

xAxies and yAxies are x and y and no more a list.
You may find more in the official chartjs doc.

Dataset don't change as you only need to make your values negative.

Answer (score 1):

You can show here an example of a pyramid with a recent version of chartjs : https://codepen.io/Alexandre973/pen/PoLJeBm

```js
var options = {
  indexAxis: 'y',
  plugins: {
    tooltip: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (c) => {          
          const value = Number(c.raw);
          const positiveOnly = value < 0 ? -value : value;
          return `${c.dataset.label}: ${positiveOnly.toString()}`;
        },
      },
    },
  },
  scales: {
    x: {
        min: -120,
        max: 120,
        ticks: {
          stepSize: 20,
          callback: (v) => v < 0 ? -v : v,
        },      
      },
  },
};
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**