# Age pyramid: 3.5.1 chartjs

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I want to create an age pyramid using pure chartjs 3.5.1. I have viewed the thread [Age pyramid chart using chart.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883315/age-pyramid-chart-using-chart-js), but one of the solutions uses react, another is not compatible with chartjs 3.+.

The result should be similar to this:
[image]

Really appreciate your help!

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use floating bars together with faking the scales, you can just use negative numbers for 1 of the 2 datasets and just invert all those numbers with all the callbacks:

```js
var options = {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ["0-10", "10-20", "20-30"],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'Girls',
        data: [
          [
            0,
            12
          ],
          [
            0,
            19
          ],
          [
            0,
            3
          ]
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'pink',
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1
      },
      {
        label: 'Boys',
        data: [
          [
            0, -7
          ],
          [
            0, -11
          ],
          [
            0, -5
          ]
        ],
        backgroundColor: 'lightBlue',
        barPercentage: 1,
        categoryPercentage: 1,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        borderSkipped: 'none' // Leave this line out to remove middle border at 0 line
      }
    ]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        callbacks: {
          label: (ttItem) => (Math.abs(ttItem.parsed.x)) // Inverse negatives to positive numbers
        }
      }
    },
    indexAxis: 'y',
    scales: {
      y: {
        stacked: true,
        grid: {
          display: false
        }
      },
      x: {
        min: -20,
        max: 20,
        ticks: {
          callback: (val) => (Math.abs(val)) // Inverrt negatives to positive numbers
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

var ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.5.1/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```