# How to make/create a population pyramid in echarts?

Tags: charts, echarts

I'm trying to create a population pyramid chart, using echarts (echarts.apache.org). I can't find an example of that kind, and couldn't find how to do it. The values of the chart should all be displayed as positive. A chart example: https://www.internetgeography.net/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/united-kingdom-population-pyramid-2016.gif

I have tried using reverse axes bar chart, with negative numbers, but I couldn't find a way to hack the displayed negative numbers into positive ones.

Comment: Can you look the below link? It answers your question I hope.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60883315/age-pyramid-chart-using-chart-js)

Answer (score -2):

I tried modifying the stack graph and using negative input values and overwriting the display as positive (Math.abs()).

When importing the data, I multiply by -1, so the output must be positive. `valueFormatter: (value) => Math.abs(value)`

Modify [tooltip.valueFormatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#tooltip.valueFormatter)

```json
tooltip: {
  trigger: 'axis',
  axisPointer: {
    type: 'shadow'
  },
  valueFormatter: (value) => Math.abs(value)
}
```

And modify [series.label.formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.formatter) display to be positive as well `Math.abs(params.value)`

```json
label: {
  show: true,
  position: 'left',
  formatter: function (params) {
    return Math.abs(params.value);
  }
}
```

And custom [xAxis.axisLabel.formatter](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#xAxis.axisLabel.formatter)

```json
    xAxis: [
        {
            type: 'value',
            show: true,
            axisLabel: {
              formatter: function (params) {
                  return Math.abs(params);
              }
            }
        }
    ],
```

[Example](https://gist.github.com/lionants02/38981b2335999f43d9a529186601f100)
Example code with [Echarts editor](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)